# Find all substrings counts in a string

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am running a command which returns a very large string. The returned string looks like

> "foofoofoofoo Verification Completed: 6 reported messages. foo foo foo
>   Verification Completed: 0 reported messages.foofoofoofoofoofoofoo
>   Verification Completed: 2 reported messages. foo foo foo"

I am looking to parse this output and get the total sum of all values returned after "Verification Completed:", which in this case is 8.

Note: foo could be any output & Verification Completed # Reported Messages can occur numerous times in the string output.

I am looking at using awk/grep to do this. Any suggestions? I am not a huge unix/bash guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using gnu awk:

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{s+=$1} END{print s}' RS='Verification Completed:' file
8
```

**EDIT:** On your provided input:

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{s+=$1} END{print s}' RS='Verification completed: ' file
54
```

Comment: I think that is close, but here is what happened when I tried to run the command. I did a "cat" of the file http://pastebin.com/WzCRjjht  It didn't sen to work

Comment: It is because in your question you have `Completed` but your input data has `completed` (with lower case `c`)

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
egrep -o "Verification Completed: \d+" | sed "s/Verification Completed: //" | paste -s -d+ - | bc
```

Comment: Nice, if look-behinds are supported it can be a bit shorter: `grep -oP '(?<=Verification Completed: )[0-9]*' | paste -sd+ | bc`